# Get data value of more element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little application which create a `data-pref=true` when a checkbox is checked and toggle it in `data-pref=false` when unchecked.

To recognize, the checkbox have also a `data-column`.

here an exemple:
js:

```
$('#dropContent [data-pref=true]')[0].data('column')
```

html:

```
 <div id="dropContent">
        <input data-column="id" data-pref="false" type="checkbox">id
        <br />
        <input data-column="weight" data-pref="true" type="checkbox">weight
    </div>
```

I need in order of the click `[0][1][2]` to take the data-column value automatically, but with `.data('column')`, `.attr` and `.prop` isn't possible...

when first `data-pref` became true take value [0]
$('#dropContent [data-pref=true]')[0]
when second `data-pref` became true take value [1]
$('#dropContent [data-pref=true]')[1]
etc...

this function save preference of column selected by user, when user select a column (this take `data-pref=true[0]`), when user deselect a column [this take `data-pref=false[0]`).
when page was resized my table search `data-pref=true` and i need to have the value of `data-column` to replace the default column with clicked by user...

Comment: what's `[0][1][2]`? 3 single item arrays?

Comment: Why is it not possible?

Comment: i do: $('#dropContent [data-pref=true]')[0] for first check

Comment: $('#dropContent [data-pref=true]')[1] for second check etc...

Comment: @Il_Sapo you don't know how to use a loop?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't _just_ want to know which items are selected, but the _order_ in which they were selected?

Comment: i say how to use loop, but i can't because i need to do a loop like this: `$('#dropContent [data-pref=true]')[i].data('column')`

Comment: @SpoonMeiser i need to know the order because this function save column selected by users and if page size change, this save preference.

Comment: Perhaps give some examples of what your users might do, and what you want the results to be, so we can better understand what you're actually asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$($('#dropContent [data-pref=true]')[nrPriority]).data('column');`

Problem was: `.data` function only with `$('')` declaration ....

Comment: Did you know .eq()

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map().get()`:

```
 $('#dropContent :checkbox').change(function (){
      var cols = $('#dropContent [data-pref=true]').map(function (i, el){
          return $(el).data('column');
      }).get();
      console.log(cols);
 });
```

`.map()` will iterate over the element checkboxes which  are having specific `data-pref` attribute and `get()` will get you the values in an array.

https://jsfiddle.net/gy3prrgg/2/

Comment: will it log an empty array if console cols?
Here is a jsfiddle
 https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/gy3prrgg/
Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You have to put this in **change** event then. Currently it is logging on Dom ready so it is logging empty array.

Comment: @ user2181397 result: [][][][][]

Comment: I did,but it still logging an empty array.
https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/gy3prrgg/1/ .Is it possible you can share a jsfiddle?

Comment: @user2181397 https://jsfiddle.net/gy3prrgg/2/ my mistake first arg in the map method is index just changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop

```
var column =[];
$('#dropContent [data-pref=true]').each(function(i,v){
  column.push($(v).attr('data-column'));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6usgnker/

Comment: with ".attr" ".prop" and ".data" i always have error

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to target all the items and not just one.

If you use the selector `$('#dropContent [data-pref=true]')` it returns an array, which can be looped:

```
$(function() {
   $('#dropContent [data-pref=true]').each( function(index) {
       var c = $(this).data('column');
       console.log( c );
   });
});
```

Inside the `each()` you can process your data, like adding it to an array or writing it inside an element.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: this.data is not a function